# Quando usar SET e SELECT?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Sei que como em praticamente todas as questões relacionadas a "*um ou outro*" devem existir situações em que é melhor utilizar `SET` ou `SELECT`, em uma *procedure* (por exemplo).

No trabalho temos o costume de sempre usar `SELECT`, mesmo que para atribuir valor a apenas uma variável, ex:

```
@declare @variavel varchar(2)
select @variavel = 'ok'
```

Esta é a melhor prática ou por ser uma atribuição simples seria melhor utilizar `SET`? Existe alguma vantagem com relação a desempenho/memória em usar `SELECT` em situações como esta?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Eu sempre tive está dúvida, mas nunca pesquisei e inclusive isto acontece bastante comigo. No [StackOVerflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945361/set-versus-select-when-assigning-variables) em Inglês tem esse tópico explicando quando usar uma e outra, as principais diferenças são:

1. `SET` é [padrão ANSI](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_National_Standards_Institute) para atribuição de variáveis, `SELECT` não é.
2. `SET` só pode atribuir uma variável por vez, `SELECT` pode fazer várias
   atribuições ao mesmo tempo.
3. Se atribuir a partir de uma consulta, `SET` só pode atribuir um valor
   escalar. Se a consulta retorna vários valores/linhas então `SET`
   poderá ocorrer um erro. `SELECT` atribuirá um dos valores à variável e
   esconderá o fato de que vários valores foram retornados (então,
   provavelmente, nunca saberia por que algo estava errado em outro
   lugar)
4. Ao atribuir a partir de uma consulta se não houver nenhum valor
   retornado o `SET` atribuirá `NULL`, onde `SELECT` não fará a atribuição
   (portanto, a variável não será alterada de seu valor anterior). Ver código abaixo
5. No que diz respeito às diferenças de desempenho não há diferenças
   diretas entre `SET` e `SELECT`. A *capacidade de SELECT de
   fazer várias atribuições* em uma única ação dá uma ligeira vantagem
   de desempenho sobre `SET`.

## Traduzindo em código item 3:

Faça um teste você mesmo através do código abaixo.

```
declare @var varchar(20)
set @var = 'Joe'
set @var = (select Campo from SuaTabela)
select @var 

select @var = Campo from SuaTabela
select @var
```

O primeiro código vai retornar a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

O segundo irá te retornar um valor.

## Traduzindo em código item 4:

```
declare @var varchar(20)
set @var = 'Joe'
set @var = (select name from master.sys.tables where name = 'qwerty')
select @var /* @var Agora é null */
--SAÍDA NULL

set @var = 'Joe'
select @var = name from master.sys.tables where name = 'qwerty' -- AQUI NÃO É ATRIBUÍDO NULL
select @var
--SAÍDA Joe
```

É bem comum usarmos no sistema em que trabalho `SELECT` em `FUNCTIONS` para concatenar valores separados por virgula em vez de exibir um por linha.

***Na pratica***

Imagine que desejo saber todos os e-mails de seus clientes e estes devem vim separados por virgula em uma único resultado.

Uma `FUNCTION` que resolveria seu problema será algo como:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fncEmails](@IDCliente int)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @RETORNO VARCHAR(MAX)

        SELECT @retorno = COALESCE(@retorno + ', ', '') + Email
        FROM Clientes 
   RETURN @retorno
END
```

Resultado:

```
'marconimbarroso@gmail.com, teste@gmail.com, alguem@outlook.com'
```

## [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d540c/4)

Comment: Eu nem sabia que o padrão ANSI previa setar valores de variáveis! Pensei que o ANSI era puramente declarativo

Answer (score 0):

Por trabalhar com *mysql*, adotei as práticas a seguir também no *sql server*:

- utilizo `set` para atribuição de valor a variáveis de controle;
- utilizo `select` para os demais casos.

Em outras palavras, quando preciso inicializar uma variável que é utilizada para controle de um *loop*, por exemplo, uso o `set` (ex `set @contador = 0`); quando a atribuição depender de qualquer consulta à base, uso o `select` (ex `select @contador = count(*) from usuarios`). Como a diferença de performance é praticamente inexistente, não há problemas na execução.

Note que poderia usar o `set` mesmo com consultas à base (ex `set @contador = (select count(*) from usuarios)`), mas acredito que fique mais complexo para leitura.

Answer (score 0):

Sempre tive a impressão de que o uso do `SET` para simples atribuições fosse mais rápido, por crer que por não envolver mecanismos de banco de dados fosse de execução mais simples e rápida.

Mas em testes que fiz em `loops` onde coloquei 3 comandos `SET` e um comando `SELECT` com as 3 atribuições, a performance do segundo foi 30% melhor.