# Como verificar Null em um select @Local_Variavel

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, null

Como definir um valor padrão para uma varável local, caso o select que deveria "setar" a mesma retorne `NULL`? Por exemplo:

```
DECLARE @Minha_Var VARCHAR(70)
SELECT @Minha_Var = Nome FROM CLIENTES WHERE Id = 10
```

Esta consulta pode retornar `NULL`, certo? Como definir um valor padrão caso isso aconteça?

Comment: Ricardo, postei funcionando.

Comment: @RaoniBZ Obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente

Comment: Se trocar para `SET` a variável  `@Minha_Var`não atribui `NULL` caso seja esse o retorno e você já tenha um valor antes. Veja: [Quando usar SET e SELECT?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/241884/quando-usar-set-e-select/241890#241890)

Comment: @Marconi Obrigado pela dica. Aliás, ótima didática no resposta do post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o CASE:

```
DECLARE @Minha_Var VARCHAR(70);

SELECT @Minha_Var = NOME
FROM CLIENTES 
WHERE ID = 10

SELECT (CASE @Minha_Var WHEN NULL THEN '1' ELSE '2' END) NOME


Você pode trazer diversos resultados:

SELECT (CASE @Minha_Var WHEN NULL THEN 'José' ELSE @Minha_Var END) NOME
SELECT (CASE @Minha_Var WHEN NULL THEN (SELECT NOME FROM CLIENTES WHERE ID = 1) ELSE @Minha_Var END) NOME
```

Answer (score 2):

O SQL SERVER dispõe da função [ISNULL](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql) e da função [COALESCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms190349(v=sql.120).aspx) que torna seu código bem mais elegante e limpo.

Ficaria assim seu código.

```
declare @CLIENTES table
(
    id int,
    Nome varchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO @CLIENTES VALUES
(1, NULL),
(2, 'Jõao')

SELECT id, ISNUll(Nome, 'Meu Nome') as 'Com ISNUll', COALESCE(Nome, 'Meu Nome') as 'com COALESCE'
FROM @CLIENTES

DECLARE @Minha_Var VARCHAR(70)
SELECT @Minha_Var = ISNUll(Nome, 'Meu Nome') FROM @CLIENTES WHERE Id = 1
SELECT @Minha_Var = COALESCE(null, 'Meu Nome') FROM @CLIENTES WHERE Id = 1

SELECT  ISNULL(null, 'Meu Nome') AS Using_ISNULL
SELECT COALESCE(null, 'Meu Nome')  AS Using_ISNULL
```